# How can I remove crouton targets?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, crouton-os

I have installed multiple targets to test them all and now I would like to remove some that are not working well with xenial. There's no information on the [crouton github wiki](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/wiki/Crouton-Command-Cheat-Sheet) on how to remove targets, only how to install and update them. What command should I use to remove targets?

Should I just edit the file `/etc/crouton/targets` within my chroot and then remove packages like [kde](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79636/how-to-remove-all-traces-of-kde-installed)?

Thanks!

Comment: There may be an answer here> https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton/issues/717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no builtin way to do this - just as you said remove it from the /etc/crouton/targets and then you have to manually delete the packages themselves. To do this you should do just:

```
sudo apt-get remove <comma,sep,list,packages>
```

(or apt-get purge) It means you need to know these though.